# Install Different Applications Using a Single Renamed Installer

Tags: install4j

I have an application that has two different brandings which are selected using a VM parameter (set in the .vmoptions file). It is possible to create two different installers with different applicationIds and names, one setting a “branding” value to “A” and another which sets the value to “B.” However, because the resulting installers would be different files I would need to basically duplicate all testing efforts (which for medical applications can be quite immense) even though the installed applications are the exact same. Is it possible to install two different applications (different applicationIds, names, etc.) using the exact same installer and detecting from the filename whether branding A or B needs to be applied?

(I’m currently using install4j 8 but an update to a newer version would be possible if it would solve this problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the file name in scripts from

```
context.getMediaName()
```

and execute actions conditionally based on that name. However, the application ID is fixed can cannot be changed at runtime.

Comment: I’m guessing that’s true for all attributes of the <application> node?

Comment: Yes, that is correct except for the application name which can contain an installer variable.